# Developer-friendly OBD-II port automobile diagnostic tool?

Tags: android, hardware, obd-ii

I am looking to streamline some data I record about my cars. My current approach is a manually edited spreadsheet with a ton of columns, which I must fill in at every fill-up and servicing. I have begun creating an android app which will save to a hosted database instead, but I'd like to simplify it even further. Rather than requiring input such as Odometer, trip, oil life, etc, I'd like to grab those from the **OBD-II** diagnostic port.

I've seen several which have their own applications, but I am looking for one which supports third party polling and APIs. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Are you looking to give your app the ability to read data directly from OBD-II scanners? If so, apps like Torque are able to communicate with a large amount of scanners because CAN has a lot of documentation about it.

Comment: I'm looking to build my own app for personal use (and just practice with android) so I'd prefer a scanner which is open, rather than another app which can communicate. I will look in to that however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in general these ODB2 Bluetooth adapters are working with a modem protocol with AT commands. So basically you can connect to them via Bluetooth serial protocol and send in commands. A starting point in terms of documentation and which Bluetooth adapter to get is here:

http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development

Comment: That answered so many questions, thank you for the link!